# PHP How to get the text part before <br>?

Tags: php, regex

There are some text, format like:

```
text part1
<br />
text part2
```

How to use php regular-expression get the only the text: `text part1`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not a regex.

Comment: Is there no getadjacenttext function in PHP DOM? I remember when programming in Visual Basic this was one of my favorite functions when dissecting HTML. This seems like a perfect example of its usefulness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or like this

```
preg_match('@(?P<before>.+)(?:<br\s*/>|<br\s*>)@Uis', $str, $matches);
echo $matches['before'];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$str  = "text part1 <br />text part2";

$arr = explode("<br />",$str);

print $arr[0];//text part1
```